# Laravel Use different queue connection to dispatch Jobs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue, laravel-5.1

I am using **laravel 5.1**  and i am using the dispatch method to push the job onto the queue.
But there are two kind of jobs and i have created and two queues for that in **sqs**.
How should i achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
//code to be used in the controller (taken from @jedrzej.kurylo above)
$job = (new SendReminderEmail($user))->onQueue('emails');
$this->dispatch($job);
```

I think this dispatches the job on to the queue named "emails".
To execute the job dispatched on 'emails' queue:

```
//Run this command in a new terminal window
php artisan queue:listen --queue=emails
```

Comment: sorry haven't tested it

Comment: How can we print the log of this onQueue, is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 12):

In order to specify the queue you need to call **onQueue()** method on your job object, e.g.:

```
$job = (new SendReminderEmail($user))->onQueue('emails');
$this->dispatch($job);
```

If you want to send the job to a connection other than default, you need to do fetch connection manually and send the job there:

```
$connection = Queue::connection('connection_name');
$connection->pushOn('queue_name', $job)
```

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work"? This is how the official docs say it should be done https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#pushing-jobs-onto-the-queue

Comment: "This does not push jobs to different queue "connections" as defined by your queue configuration file, but only to specific queues within a single connection. " This is what the document says

Comment: Ah, so you want to change both queue and connection?

Comment: either change the queue or the connection..any thing would do

Comment: I've updated the answer. I checked how sending to a connection/queue is implemented in Laravel, it seems that above should be enough. Please let me know if there are any issues, I haven't had a chance to test it

Comment: I'd suggest this: app('queue')->connection('connection_name')->pushOn('queue_name', $job);

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest this:

```
app('queue')->connection('connection_name')->pushOn('queue_name', $job);
```

From here: [In Laravel how to create a queue object and set their connection without Facade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356124/in-laravel-how-to-create-a-queue-object-and-set-their-connection-without-facade)