# In Laravel how to create a queue object and set their connection without Facade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Lumen/Laravel I want to send a message to a given queue.

by default I have it set to Redis, what I would like is to send it to another queue server as another application will take care of it.

I know I can do `$queue->pushRaw('payload');` However there is no subsequent way for me to pick the connection.

I am aware that I can use Facade to create my Queue as such:

```
$connection = Queue::connection('connection_name');
$connection->pushOn('queue_name', $job)
```

However I'm doing this in Lumen, and would like to avoid turning on the Facade Just for this aspect. Also, I would like to know how to do this as I would like to pass by IoC through a job event handler eventually.

Version of Lumen/Laravel 5.2.

Comment: If you don't want to use the Facades, use the dependency injection container to get an instance of Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager or use the app(...) or $app->make(..) function, e.g. app("queue")->connection('connection_name');  or $app->make("queue")->connection(...) - I hope this helps - i would create a full example, but i have to go to bed now.  Also, a little bit more information about your code (from where do you send the message, etc) would be helpful if you need a full answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Mois44 alluded to, you should be able to accomplish this with the QueueManager.

The QueueManager will allow you to call the connection() method, which will return a Queue object. And from here, you can call the normal queued functions (pushOn, laterOn, etc)

```
// Returns an Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager object
$queueManager = app('queue'); 

// Returns an Illuminate\Queue\Queue object
$queue = $queueManager->connection('my-connection'); 

$queue->pushOn('queue_name', $job);
```

or all chained together

```
app('queue')->connection('my-connection')->pushOn('queue_name', $job)
```

---

Admittedly, my Lumen specific knowledge is pretty limited. If the app() method doesn't work to get an instance of the QueueMananger, then I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I know it's not ok, but THANKS you save my problem for some outher plugin that i have problems. app('queue') instead app(QueueManager::class).